# Return first 8 character regex matching

Tags: regex

I am attempting to match the first 8 characters of a domain. Currently my rules are:

*Must be only the first 8*

*If 8 characters do not exist, grab every character before `.tld`*

My regex currently looks like so: `^(www\.)?(?<domain>.+)$`

which is grabbing like `google.com`

In my case I would have it grab `google`

in the case of `thisislongerthen8characterslong.com` I would like to return `thisislo`

Comment: What happens in the case of `images.google.com` - should I get `google` or `images.g`?

Comment: @josh.trow that is correct, it would return `images.g`

Comment: Where & in what environment are you using this regex? Wouldn't it be easier to just match a domain, and use a substring method on it afterward? (BTW: `/^(www\.)?(.{1,8}(?=.*\.[^.]+$))/gm` [does the trick here](http://regex101.com/r/aY1pW4/6)

Comment: A lot depends on whether you consider `british.co.uk` to have a tld of `.uk` or `.co.uk` BTW.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
^(?:www\.)?(.{1,8}).*\.[A-Za-z0-9]+$
```

Matches:

```
google.com                        : google
thisisanenormousdomain.co.uk      : thisisan
google.co.uk                      : google.c
www.google.com                    : google
www.thisisanenormousdomain.co.uk  : thisisan
```

Technical details:

```
^(?:www\.)?(.{1,8}).*\.[A-Za-z0-9]+$
│└────┬───┘└───┬──┘└┬─┘└─────┬─────┘
│     │        │    │        └ 5. Match TLD (e.g. com, uk, org, net, etc)
│     │        │    └ 4. Match anything after the first eight characters, up until the last '.' in the url.
│     │        └ 3. Capture between one and eight characters inside a match group.
│     └ 2. Match an optional www. prefix. Do not add to match groups.
└ 1. Find the start of the string.
```

Try it: http://rubular.com/r/wLX2C9jg26

Comment: @HydraIO - No problem! I've added a technical breakdown of the regex if it helps you :)

Comment: Ah, damn, should've reloaded before commenting :( +1

Comment: I arrived here looking for something completely different, but +1 for the great explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a quantifier on the `.`:

```
^(?:www\.)?(?<domain>.{0,8}).*\..{2,3}$
```

[Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/aY0qL4/2) example

Comment: Ending with `\..{2,3}` is ancient history (and even then, rare tld's like `.museum` already existed). But from now on, don't assume a limit on the length of a tld ;) ICANN throws out new & long tld's like it's nothing.